# Incrementing a pointer while reading it?

Tags: c++, arduino

The following code comes from Arduino's "Print.cpp":

```
size_t Print::print(const __FlashStringHelper *ifsh)
{
  PGM_P p = reinterpret_cast<PGM_P>(ifsh);
  size_t n = 0;
  while (1) {
    unsigned char c = pgm_read_byte(p++);
    if (c == 0) break;
    n += write(c);
  }
  return n;
}
```

The `__FlashStringHelper` is basically a char array or string literal which is stored in PROGMEM (program memory) instead of RAM. It is declared as in WString.h:

```
class __FlashStringHelper;
#define F(string_literal) (reinterpret_cast<const __FlashStringHelper *>(PSTR(string_literal)))
```

I am interested in the `unsigned char c = pgm_read_byte(p++);` line and more spesifically the `(p++)` part. I assume that the value of the pointer p is read here and is also incremented by one byte here so that all the bytes in *ifsh can be read one after the other. Am I correct with that?

So I have 2 question considering the above;

1. What is the sequence in normal C/C++ compilers and what is the sequence in Arduino? Is the value first read and then the pointer incremented? Or is it the other way around?
2. Is the sequence always the same for C/C++ compilers or will it
   differ between them?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but where does the `__FlashStringHelper` type come from? Using double leading underscores is reserved to the "implementation" (i.e. compiler and standard library) in all scopes.

Comment: Please see my edit. Unfortunately I do not know about the leading underscores. I also don't know if the Arduino guys stick to standards or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `pgm_read_byte(p++)` is equivalent to

```
pgm_read_byte(p);
p += 1;
```

And all C or C++ compilers that follow the standard will behave that way.

Comment: It's not just C/C++, it's also Java, JavaScript, PHP, C#, D, Objective-C, ... any C-like language follows the same scheme. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators

Comment: For C++ I don't think this is entirely correct. The pointer `p` is incremented before the function executes. The equivalent code is rather `PGM_P tmp = p; p += 1; pgm_read_byte(tmp);` For most practical uses this doesn't really matter but it is possible to write code where it would matter, e.g. using an "ugly" global pointer variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's defined by C++ standard and:

1. It's the same (in this case it's post increment so it will happen after reading value from `p`)
2. Always the same.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second question, this is from c89 standard:

The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. After the result is obtained, the value of the operand is incremented.

I somehow believe that this is true for all newer c versions as well as cpp.

Arduino uses the avr-gcc compiler. So i can guess you can safely assume:

A = p++ is equal to A = p; p++;

Answer (score 1):

The post-increment operator (i.e. variable++) will increment the variable but return the old value of the variable. It is equivalent to:

```
SomeType PostIncrement(SomeType& v)
{
    SomeType oldValue = v;
    v = v + 1;
    return oldValue;
}
```

Example:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x++;
// Here x is 6 while y is 5 (i.e. the old value of x)
```

When you use post-increment on a variable you pass in a function call, the function will be called with the old value. Still the increment is done before the function call because the arguments will be fully evaluated before the call.

Example:

```
void f(int y)
{
    // When execution arrives here, x is 6 while y is 5 (i.e. the old value of x)

}

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    f(x++);
    return 0;
}
```